# Конфликт разных версий библиотек

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, плагин

Добрый день) опять имею проблемы с библиотеками.
Содержатся такие плагины в проекте:

- OpenIAB
- FaceBook
- Appodeal
- UnityAds
- Admob

Последний добавлял `Appodeal`, он добавил мне версии библиотек `9.8.0.` После чего мне необходимо было добавить `TheoremReach SDK`, который работает с версиями библиотек `9.0.1.` соответственно он запросил заменить их на `9.0.1.` Собрал проект и получил вот это:

```
SpritePacker failed to get types from Google.IOSResolver, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Error: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()


ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:371)
UnityEditor.AttributeHelper+<CallMethodsWithAttribute>c__Iterator0`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[UnityEditorInternal.PluginDesc]].MoveNext () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AttributeHelper.cs:368)
UnityEditor.PluginImporter+<GetExtensionPlugins>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/PluginImporterBindings.gen.cs:94)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.NativePlugins.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:186)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Resolver version is now: 10101
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:RegisterResolver(IResolver) (at Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/PlayServicesResolver.cs:75)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:.cctor() (at Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/ResolverVer1_1.cs:35)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()

Resolver version is now: 10102
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:RegisterResolver(IResolver) (at Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/PlayServicesResolver.cs:75)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_2:.cctor() (at Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/ResolverVer1_2.cs:33)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()

Registering resolver version 1.2.0
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_2:.cctor() (at Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/ResolverVer1_2.cs:34)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()

Resolver version is now: 10102
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:RegisterResolver(IResolver) (at Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/PlayServicesResolver.cs:75)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_2:.cctor() (at Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/ResolverVer1_2.cs:36)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()
```

Прикрепляю скрин папки `Plugins` и `PlayServicesResolver`, пришлось удалить `Google.JarResolver.dll` так как `TheoremReachSDK` добавил свой `JarResolverLib.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Вижу, вы уже пользуетесь [Google Play Resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver), но ссылку на репозиторий дам, может версия у вас не последняя. Он работает со спец файлами плагинов и решает конфликты между требуемыми для них либами.
Иногда не все плагины имеют нужный для его работы файл, тогда нужно смотреть в документации плагинов, какие библиотеки google play им нужны и дописывать ручками эти библиотеки в файлы от других плагинов (по аналогии с уже существующими), либо создавать специально для этого плагина новый файл.

Нужный файл обычно называется примерно так [имяплагина]dependencies. У AdMob - это GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml, у AdColony - ADCDependencies.cs и далее по аналогии. Полагаю, что у какого-то из сервисов есть косяк в таком файле, либо данного файла вообще нет.